# Show dynamic text in gnome topbar, In a NodeJS App

Tags: node.js, electron, gnome, gnome-shell

I am working on an electron application, a time management application. Gnome is my primary desktop environment.

I want to show a countdown timer, in my Gnome top bar. So far all my online search has not led me any where which gives me working solution how to implement in this within a NodeJs environment.

Below screenshot is from my current desktop, where **gnome-extensions** are displaying dynamic data, of my network speed and CPU/RAM usage etc.

[image: Screenshot topbar]

I want the same solution to be implement in my electron app, Hence what I am looking for is NodeJS library or any other method to integrate GJS libraries into node environment.I found one Node library called

> [dbus-next](https://github.com/dbusjs/node-dbus-next)

May be I can access the panel through d-bus and send messages to gnome shell, However I don't know how to access the gnome shell properties through dbus and manipulate it.

Any help on how to achieve above objective, and to implement this in an electron/node app would be appreciated.